# pip-3.3 install MySQL-python

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am getting an error

pip version

pip-3.3 -V 
    pip 1.4.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py3.3.egg (python 3.3)

how to install MySQLdb in Python3.3 helpp..

```
root@thinkpad:~# pip-3.3 install MySQL-python 
Downloading/unpacking MySQL-python
  Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.4.zip (113kB): 113kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package MySQL-python
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 14, in <module>
        from setup_posix import get_config
      File "./setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 14, in <module>

    from setup_posix import get_config

  File "./setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>

    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/MySQL-python
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: Sadly, MySQL-python doesn't support Python 3 right now. You'll have to either rollback to python 2.x, or use another package. [Source](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.4)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27748556/python3-4-cant-install-mysql-python (`pip install mysqlclient` - a `MySQL-python` fork).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In python3 `ConfigParser` was renamed to `configparser`. It seems `MySQL-python` does not support python3. Try:

```
$ pip install PyMySQL
```

[PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL) is a different module, but it supports python3.

Comment: how to connect pymysqldb in django?

Comment: @PyDroid As Piotr Migdal said in his comment in Question. you  should use mysqlclient for MySQL for Python3 in Django. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers 
Its recommended choice for using MySQL with Django.

Answer (score 4):

In python3, install MySQL-python-1.2.5 by [source](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip#md5=654f75b302db6ed8dc5a898c625e030c), and before that, you need to modify source as mentioned below:

- Replace `ConfigParser` by `configparser`  in file MySQL-python-1.2.5/setup_posix.py file
- Modify line 191, `except TypeError, m:` to `except TypeError as m:` in file MySQL-python-1.2.5/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/cursors.py file
- Modify line 250, `except TypeError, msg:` to `except TypeError as msg:` in same cursors.py file
- Modify line 36, `raise errorclass, errorvalue` to `raise errorclass(errorvalue)` in MySQL-python-1.2.5/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/MySQLdb/connections.py file

To understand more, see [Python3 porting guide](http://docs.pythonsprints.com/python3_porting/py-porting.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install --allow-external mysql-connector-python
```

Edit settings.py

```
'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
```