# Python3.4 can't install mysql-python

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x

```
# pip3.4 install mysql-python
  Downloading/unpacking mysql-python
  Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108kB): 108kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/mysql-python/setup.py) egg_info for package mysql-python
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/mysql-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        from setup_posix import get_config
      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/mysql-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/mysql-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>

    from setup_posix import get_config

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/mysql-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>

    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/mysql-python
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: are you trying to install a package for python 2 in python 3? I think that package is for `python < 3.0`

Comment: MySQL-python does not support Python 3.

Comment: try sudo apt-get install mysql-client

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Resolved:

```
 pip3.4 install --allow-external mysql-connector-python
```

#### Edit settings.py

```
'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
```

Comment: I've seen questions from users struggling to get MySQL connector to work. The Django docs recommend mysqlclient.

Comment: where you able to install `mysql-python` after that?

Comment: this answer doesnt help me. the answer posted by Alasdair below helped.

Comment: DEPRECATION: --allow-external has been deprecated and will be removed in the future. Due to changes in the repository pr
otocol, it no longer has any effect.

Answer (score 19):

[MySQL-python 1.2.5](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5) does not support Python 3. The [Django 1.7 docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers) recommend the fork [mysqlclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient).

Answer (score 0):

Under Centos: yum install mysql-devel
pip3 install mysqlclient

Answer (score -4):

On Ubuntu or Debian, just sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb. It worked for me