# Cannot install MySQL connector/python on mac for python 3

Tags: python, mysql, database

I have done huge research and I still cant find way to install the mysql connector for my mac. I tried many solutions from stackoverflow that I found and still can't do it.

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python:
>   can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

It gives me this error when I try to install `sudo python setup.py install`

I also tried homebrew and cant find any way but after I installed the connector through the website, it said that the installation was successful.

```
import mysql.connector
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ImportError: No module named 'mysql'
```

I also get the error above.

Comment: Try to use `homebrew`, `virtualenv` and `pip` instead of executing `setup.py` mannually

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27749535/5032369 thank u for your help... this answer solved my issue....Thank you so muchh i have researching for more than 12 hours

Comment: getting this error while running my code on Terminal


>> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'


I've upgraded Python to 3.9.1 version, pip to 20.3.4, it says mysql.connector successfully installed yet I am not able to import it.

Answer (score 1):

I am using macOS High Sierra bit confusing because two python version is available python2 is already installed, python3 i have installed through brew.

```
python --version
```

Python 2.7.10

```
python3 --version
```

Python 3.7.0

```
which python
```

/usr/bin/python

```
which python3
```

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3

**install mysql-connector**

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
pip3 install mysql-connector-python
```

*if you getting any error like bellow *

Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql_connector.so'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

*Try this*

```
pip install mysql-connector-python --user
pip3 install mysql-connector-python --user
```